# ASP.NET / OWIN/ ADAL Azure AD authentication with in app roles defined and assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an app using ASP.NET WebAPI 2.2 that requires login via Azure AD for which I'm using ADAL/OWIN, but the app must have app specific permissions and roles that can be assigned to users who log in to it (a bit like SharePoint groups). The client can't use Azure AD groups, claims or Azure app permissions to assign rights/create groups as it is set up/maintained by a third party.

So, if the app is authenticating users against Azure AD, am I able to use the SQLRoleProvider to create/maintain a permission set and assign them to users within the app? I've searched for a while and not found anything that exactly fits my use scenario. Currently I'm thinking I may have to roll my own role provider.

EDITED for clarity.

Comment: Did you managed to resolve your issue? I'm struggling with similar case where I can't allow user to manage roles/groups at AAD

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom role provider in Azure AD. When used, each user is given a role (or rather, place in a role) at the time the user is granted access to the application. I used this blog post to get started when creating a simple role-based mvc app for a customer:
[Azure Active Directory, now with Group Claims and Application Roles](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles.aspx).

We used this to separate between regular and admin users of an application we built.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is my back pocket solution. Because the client doesn't own (or have any admin rights to) the azure AD app config that I'm using to hang their application from, I'd like to keep roles / permissions within the app for the sake of ease of extensibility, rather than having to go through a third party change control process whenever a new requirement comes along, or I need to change something in the app config.

Comment: gotcha, that makes sense.

Comment: Looks like the link moved to here: 
https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2014/12/18/azure-active-directory-now-with-group-claims-and-application-roles/